# Servlet modification to let it read relative paths

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, velocity

I am new to `Java EE`. I am trying to modify an `init()` code in a servlet. I have created a loadConfiguration(config) method that is called in the init() method. I've also uploaded a velocity.property file in the `WEB-INF` folder. The `loadConfiguration()` method is specified below:-

```
protected Properties loadConfiguration (ServletConfig config) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException  {
    String propsFile = config.getInitParameter(INIT_PROPS_KEY);
    Properties p = new Properties();

    if ( propsFile != null ) {
      InputStream iStream = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream( propsFile );

      if ( iStream != null ) {
        p.load( iStream );
      }
    }

    return p;
    }
```

When I try to run this app in weblogic, I get a 403 error telling me that server understood the request but is refusing to comply.

**Is there any workaround for this issue ?**

*Any Help will be appreciated !*

Answer (score 0):

Response `status code 403` means the servlet is `forbidden`. Check if you have any security constraints defined in your web application.

Comment: I can't find any security constraints that would prevent the initialization of servlet. Furthermore, I can run the application using Tomcat. However, when I run it in weblogic, I encounter this problem.